# BotFramework: PromptDialog.Choice still doesn't return partial matches

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using bot framework .net builder 3.8.2 & PromptDialog.Choice does not return partial matches. This question has been asked before and according to the answer given this should be working in the current version. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please show steps to reproduce your problem, expected behavior, and provide a link to the previous question (if it helps add context). See also: [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

The [Pull Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/2851) containing the fix wasn't merged yet, that's why is still not working in 3.8.2.